Forcing persistence of Chronicle-map instance to disk via periodic fsync() - any issues?
I'm considering using Chronicle-map for an application but I'd like better guarantees about when the data is synced to disk rather than just relying on the OS.
I am using the map to hold index entries (e.g. file offsets of data of interest in a large data set)  If there is a crash, I can scan the source files and recreate the entries I would normally have put in Chronicle-map, but I'd like to limit how often I need to do this.  So I'm thinking I put the entries into Chronicle-map (created using the createPersistedTo() option) and periodically calling fsync() on the underlying file - each time I call fsync() I update a checkpoint, and if there is a crash, I only need to check the entries since the last checkpoint.
My question is: has anyone done anything like this? Any gotchas that I need to be aware of? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?
So far I have not tried this - it is an implementation that I am considering and I haven't seen anything in the documentation that addresses this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
